# shell_exec in PHP is not working

Tags: php, shell, shell-exec

shell_exec()
is not working on my localhost. I read a lot of websites to resolve this issue but can't find a solution.
This code:

```
    $output = shell_exec("env");
    print "<pre>$output</pre>";
```

Doesn't give any output.

I checked in php.ini `disable_functions` but `shell_exec` is not disabled.
I did `error_reporting = E_ALL` but again no output (no error). All I get is just a blank screen. Even `safe_mode` is off.

If I write `echo "BULB";` after the above code it is printing "BULB".

What could be the issue?

Comment: If you simply run  `env` in your console, you get the output?

Comment: I am getting this output `ReferenceError: env is not defined`

Comment: Do other commands like `ls` or `dir` work?

Comment: That error message looks like JavaScript to me. What shell are you using?

Comment: @Ke Vin also `ls` and `dir` returns the same thing.

Comment: Thinking about it, perhaps you misunderstood @Federico's comment and executed the command from the JS console in your browser...He meant to open up a command prompt / terminal emulator and run the command from there. In order for us to help you, we need to know more about your system. In particular, it would be useful to know the operating system and the default shell.

Comment: @Tom Fenech the code mentioned in question is in myfile.php. It is running on xampp with OS as Windows 8

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What info are you expecting to get from `env`? From your comments, it seems to me as if you're trying to use a Linux command on a Windows system -- that's never going to work.

On Linux systems, the `env` command on its own like that returns a list of environment variables that have been defined. However `env` is not a valid command in Windows.

If you're simply looking for the list of environment variables, this can actually be obtained in PHP without having to go to a shell command. PHP has a built-in global variable `$_ENV` which contains a copy of all the environment variables that were defined when the program stated. Simply `print_r($_ENV)` to see them.

On the other hand, if you really need to use `shell_exec()` for some reason, then you need to take into account the operating system that you're using. On Linux you would use `env` command. The equivalent on Windows is `set` without any arguments. So your code becomes:

```
$output = shell_exec("set");
```

Note that the format of the output may not be identical to what you'd get on Linux, so if you're parsing it, that code will have to change too.

If you need your code to be able to run on multiple platforms then you would need to write additional code before the `shell_exec()` call to determine the operating system and work out the correct command to use.

Comment: In general, your point regarding portability of calls to `shell_exec` is valid but `env` _is_ a valid command in Windows.

Comment: @TomFenech - I just opened my dos prompt and typed 'env', and got the classic `'env' is not recognised as an internal or external command.`. So if it is a Windows command, it isn't in my system's path.

Comment: Fair enough - it's a valid command on my system (Windows 8.1) in the command prompt.

Comment: hmm, I'm also on Win 8.1, so I don't know what the difference is.